# Passing Variable from Python to Node

Tags: javascript, python, parameter-passing, python-3.7

> Python Script

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import check_output

def run_node():
    sp = subprocess.Popen([
         "node",
         "E:/dev/main.js",
         "foo",
         "bar"
    ])
```

> main.js

```
var arguments = process.argv;
console.log(process);
console.log(arguments);
```

I run my python script and it calls the specified node `main.js` file.

Output for `process` is : `[AsyncFunction: process]`

Output for `arguments` is : `undefined`

I've also tried `subprocess.check_output` with `input` to test:

```
run_test = subprocess.check_output(
    ["node", "E:/dev/main.js", "foo", "bar"]
    input=b"foo",
)
```

But to similar avail.

How do I pass a variable such as `foo` or `bar` from my python script to my node js file?

Comment: `process` should normally be an object, not an `AsyncFunction`. Did you accidentally overwrite the global variable `process` with some other value, or maybe import something different with the same name?

Comment: @Thomas yes man, thank you lol. I had an async function named `process` haha. Good call.  Works now :)

Comment: Is there a way to send arguments back from the node script to the python script?